# Dual-monitor setup with custom desktop environment and Compiz

Tags: desktop-environment, multi-monitor, compiz

I have two monitors that are both connected to my computer.
I want to have them un-mirrored, and it works fine in Cinnamon (after tweaking some settings), but I can't find a way to do this in a **custom** desktop environment with Compiz.

Here is the script that starts my DE:

```
#!/bin/bash
docky &
compiz
```

I'm running Linux Mint 17 (Based on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr).

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out: All I had to do was to add the line `xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1280x1024 --output DVI-1 --mode 1024x768 --left-of DVI-0` to the beginning of my DE script.

To find the values for the `--output` options, just type `xrandr`. Here's the output of `xrandr` on my machine right now:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2304 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-0 connected primary 1280x1024+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```